# celery: how to use celery.utils.worker_direct

Tags: python, celery

I am working on a project using Celery for distributing tasks. In order to route a task to a specific worker (because it needs specific files, created by a previous task), I am trying to use [celery.utils.worker_direct](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.utils.html#celery.utils.worker_direct).

What I'm doing is basically this:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_A(self, arg):
    worker = str(self.request.hostname)
    # ...
    s = task_B.s(arg1, worker)
    s.delay()

@app.task
def task_B(arg1, worker):
    task_C.apply_async((arg1, arg2), queue=worker_direct(worker))

@app.task
def task_C(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

When `task_C.apply_async((arg1, arg2), queue=worker_direct(worker))` is executed, I get this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Queue' has no len()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
# task_A
worker = worker_direct(self.request.hostname).name

# task_B
task_C.apply_async((arg1, arg2), queue=worker)
```